# Testing install failures in Burn

Tags: testing, error-handling, wix, burn, windows-installer

I'm working on a Burn bootstrapper application the purpose of which is to install a number of MSI packages. I would like to test the scenario where one of the package installations fails. Is there a way to create an MSI package which always fails when you try to install it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to add a reference to WixFailWhenDeferred Custom action.

Check [this tutorial](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixfailwhendeferred.html).

You can also set it always like WIXFAILWHENDEFERRED=1 or to pass is from the bundle.